# Visually align columns when displaying a CSV file in notepadqq

Tags: notepadqq

In notepadqq (v2.0.0-beta+git), how could I force columns to have an optimized (automatic based on file content) fixed width when displaying a CSV file?

I want to do that so that every "column" is visually aligned, even so there may be lot of free space in some row, and for the position of the end of each line to be at the same place.

e.g. from:

```sh
a,b,c,some stuff,"some, other, stuff",d
y,x,z,t,cool,thing
```

to:

```sh
a, b, c, some stuff,"some, other, stuff",     d<EOL>
y, x, z,          t,                cool, thing<EOL>
```

Notice: I do have plenty of fields containing text and having commas. They are normally double quoted.

--

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51471554/10622916

Comment: Not working: `bash: column: command not found`

Comment: Using your favourite search engine might help. Proposed search string ["ubuntu column"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+column). This way you could find https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/column.1.html